# jquery how to make sure that all the images has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload

```
var nowCount = 0;
$("img").load(function(){
imgCount++;
if (nowCount == imgsCount)
do something ... 
});
```

imgsCount :: the number of images that i want to load

1- is this code compatible with all browsers ?
2- how can i know if an image failed to load ?

Comment: How and when are you loading these images? When do you want to know if the images are loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of suspicious code here:

- Img**s**Count vs. ImgCount
- what is `nowCount` supposed to do?
- Are you sure about the `unload` event for the IMG tag?

If you want to load images in the background, you need to create a new image element and attach a source attribute.